Test that shows FileSystemWatcher is working incorrectly
While working on legacy codebase, I stumbled on the following code in OnCreated event handler for a FileSystemWatcher:
        string directoryPathToWatch = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PathFile"]; // Path to directory that is being watched for newly created '.txt' files

        private void fileSystemWatcher_Created(object sender, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(300000);

            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(directoryPathToWatch);
            FileSystemInfo[] files = di.GetFileSystemInfos("*.txt");
            var dir = files.OrderBy(f => f.Name);

            foreach (var file in dir)
            {
                // processes each file and after it is done, moves it to Output folder . . .
            }
        }

Why I suspect the following code is incorrect is because of the Thread.Sleep(300000) operation which is there to wait for multiple files to be created so they can be processed in order dictated by the filename (e.g. 0001.txt, 0002.txt, etc).
As per my understanding, the code is also wrong since for each newly created .txt file in the directory, a new Create event is being raised which is being processed in a new thread(fileSystemWatcher_Created method). When the 1-st thread for the first created file is spun, it starts processing all the files that are found in the directory, but when the subsequent threads (for the 2-nd, 3-rd, 4-th, etc. files) are being executed they will try to process files that may have been moved by the 1-st thread and they do not exist in the directory anymore.
What I have tried is to create new files almost at the same time using multiple threads using a Barrier, but the test passed.
readonly string OUT_FOLDER_PATH = "D:\\path_to_directory_where_windows_service_Outputs_processed_files";

        [Test]
        public void Test_fsw_fails()
        {
            string sampleDataFolderPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "SampleData"); // folder where sample data is located

            string[] inputDataFileNames = Enumerable.Range(0, 59)
                        .Select(n => $"{n.ToString("0000")}.txt")
                        .ToArray();

            using (Process applicationProcess = new Process()
            {
                StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("D:\\path_to_windows_service_executable.exe")
                {
                    CreateNoWindow = false
                }
            })
            {
                applicationProcess.Start();
                Barrier moveInputDataBarrier = new Barrier(59);

                Task[] moveInputDataTasks = Enumerable.Range(0, 59)
                    .Select(n => new Task(() =>
                    {
                        string localSampleDataFolderPath = sampleDataFolderPath;
                        string localFileName = inputDataFileNames[n];
                        int localN = n;

                        moveInputDataBarrier.SignalAndWait();

                        File.Copy(Path.Combine(localSampleDataFolderPath, localFileName), Path.Combine(OUT_FOLDER_PATH, localFileName));
                    }))
                    .ToArray();

                foreach (var task in moveInputDataTasks)
                {
                    task.Start();
                }

                Task.WaitAll(moveInputDataTasks);

                Thread.Sleep(380000);
                applicationProcess.Kill();
            }

            Assert.That(Directory.EnumerateFiles(OUT_FOLDER_PATH).Count(), Is.EqualTo(59)); // Correct number of files processed

            foreach (var actualOutputFileFullPath in Directory.EnumerateFiles(OUT_FOLDER_PATH, "*.txt"))
            {
                byte[] actualOutputFileContent = File.ReadAllBytes(actualOutputFileFullPath);
                byte[] expectedOutputFileContent = File.ReadAllBytes(Path.Combine(sampleDataFolderPath, Path.GetFileName(actualOutputFileFullPath)));

                Assert.That(actualOutputFileContent, Is.EquivalentTo(expectedOutputFileContent)); // Check for content equality
            }
        }

Searching Stackoverflow for answers I have stumbled on multiple suggestions where people advise to avoid FileSystemWatcher as it is unreliable and other integration techniques should be used Processing Folder With Multiple Files Using FileSystemWatcher and C#. What other methods should be considered as an alternative if possible?

In the past when I've done this I've used the event to post file names into a list and started a timer that checks every second of a file is still growing, and if not, can it be opened in read mode, and when it can then hand off to some other background process to consume the file. All that the event does is put new file names of potential interest into the list. It is the timer that reviews the list every second and works out of a file should be acted upon. When finished it is removed from the list so it is only processed once

@flackoverstow same as the accepted answer of the linked question I guess https://stackoverflow.com/a/48290711/21175857

The implementation shown is pretty much working by chance of it does at all. FSW has its quirks, sure. But it definitely has its place.

@Fildor could you restate your first sentence, I have hard time understanding it. Are you saying it works by chance, and the code is broken?

I would say so, yes. Any event handler containing a Thread.Sleep I would consider fundamentally broken, let alone one that sleeps for 5 minutes. - oh and the "of" should have been an "if" in my above comment *g

^^ now that said, not only is it any event handler, but a handler of an event from FSW, which are notorious for the fact they should execute as short a time as possible.

Once upon a time the documentation of the FileSystemWatcher included the warning "Keep your event handling code as short as possible". I am no longer seeing it, so Microsoft might have resolved this issue. In any case seeing the Thread.Sleep(300000); inside the event handler rings alarm bells inside my head.

After further research I have found out that the FileSystemWatcher is not reliable. It will start dropping raised events due to it's internal buffer overflowing and since it is expensive (also not guaranteed to fix the problem) to increase it's size, it is recommended to use a solution similar to the one in the linked in the question.
I am still unable to write a reliable failing test (in fact all the test cases that I have tried passed) that will show that the given code is not working. I am still waiting for an answer.

I use a concurrent queue and add "the event" to the queue; and start a "task" to process the queue if one hasn't been started previously. No problems. Ever.

So, cars are unreliable because they will no longer drive when they run out of gas? That's expected behavior, so I would not count that as "unreliable".

The thing is, since it is a legacy app that has been running for a long time, and it is assumed that is does not have any problems, I need some tests (Failing) as an evidence in order to be changed/fixed. Reliability is paramount, and the current solution does not meet the standards in my opinion (and judging from the comments, others opinion as well).

As I see it, the implementation defeats having an FSW in the first place. It violates so much of the recommended use that it simply doesn't matter any more. So: if this has been running for years, behaving as expected by your team, there is no urgent reason to change it. If you want or have to upgrade to a more recent dotnet and want to ensure "best practices" on the go, I'd rather recommend a "mostly" rewrite with tests that prove the new code to still function properly.

If in order to get a green light for that you need to have a red test: check for that buffer overflow. My bets would be on it happening.

@GerrySchmitz instead of using a ConcurrentQueue<T> it's better to use a BlockingCollection<T>, like in this answer by rene. The BlockingCollection<T> and the Channel<T> are the go to solutions for implementing the producer-consumer pattern in .NET.

"Blocking" is redundant. The "producer" is the "FileWatcher" (which you have no control over); the "event handler" is a middle man; the "consumer" is a single task that "ends" when the queue is "empty"; there is nothing to "block". The single event handler starts a task to read the queue if one is not running. Keep it simple. It's not a "typical" producer-consumer "pattern".

@GerrySchmitz could you upload your non-blocking ConcurrentQueue<T>-based solution somewhere, and share the link, so that we can see it and evaluate it? My best guess is that it should look like rene's original implementation, before switching to the BlockingCollection<T>, that featured a dreadful tight loop.

Why is the question closed? I'm still waiting for an answer on a positive failing test. Even less do I get how is it "not focused", as it clearly states the reason in the heading, an example of the problem is given and "what i've tried so far" has been given (which fails).

The solution calls for a "queue"; not a "list" that you have to treat as a queue. The BlockingCollection is "over-engineering" on the one hand; and "under" on the other; for this scenario. A ConcurrentQueue is "just right" (IMO). And less code without breaking a sweat.

@GerrySchmitz the BlockingCollection<T> by default is a queue. It supports the notion of "completion", which is crucial for implementing a producer-consumer scenario. The ConcurrentQueue<T> doesn't support this notion, so the consumer doesn't know what to do when the queue is empty. Is it empty temporarily or is it empty forever? In the first case, how to get a notification when the queue contains again something to be consumed? The BlockingCollection<T> is designed specifically to solve these problems, and it does so with a simple and intuitive API. Nothing over-engineered about it.
